# Passing props from host to a microfrontend remote app using module federation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-5, micro-frontend

I am trying to pass props (value="hello") from my host app to the remote app using props. But my props are coming as undefined in the remote app. Please help!

I have shared below my webpack config and how I am passing and consuming props in host and remote apps.

Host app webpack config and relevant code:

```
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        remote:"remote@http://localhost:5500/remoteEntry.js"
      },
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    })

import Counter from "remote/Counter"
const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <div>Name: host</div>
    <Counter value={"hello"} />
  </div>
);
```

Remote app webpack config and the relevant code:

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "remote",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        "./Counter":"./src/Counter.jsx"
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          eager:true,
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          eager:true,
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    })

const Counter = (props) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState("")
    console.log({ props })  //I expect "value" prop to be present here
    return (
        <div style={{ color: 'blue', backgroundColor: "pink" }}>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(prev => prev + 1)}>Click</button>
            Counter: {count}
            <p>{serverData} {props && props.hii}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

const App = (props) => (
  <div className="container">
    <div>Name: remote</div>
    <Counter />
  </div>
);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing { }.

```
console.log({ props })
```

just like that `console.log(props)`